# Bounded, aperiodic irrationals with bounded, aperiodic sum

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

For an irrational $q$ with continued fraction expansion $[q_0;q_1,q_2 \dots]$, say $q_i$ is the $i$-th patial quotient of $q$. I have the following question:

> Are there any nontrivial examples of distinct irrationals $\alpha,\beta >0$ such that $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\alpha + \beta$ have bounded, aperiodic partial quotients?

My guess is that such pairs of irrationals do exist. But constructing an example seems beyond me.  By nontrivial, I mean $\alpha,\beta$ are not rational multiples of each other, nor have integral difference. (Should 'integral' be replaced by 'rational'?) In fact, $\{ 1, \alpha, \beta\}$ should be $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent.

Comment: Where did you find this question?  As it stands, you've asked this question without much context.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I came up with it.

Comment: Note that the $q_i$ are usually called "partial quotients"; "convergents" are the actual fractions that approximate $q$ well.—Also, what precisely do you mean by "nontrivial"? Does $\beta=2\alpha$ count as nontrivial?

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry, I had an exam the minute after I was typing this post. Yes, by nontrivial I meant nonintegral differences and nonintegral multiples. Perhaps 'nonintegral' should be changed to 'nonrational', but I'm not exactly sure how that affects the problem. Whatever makes it most interesting. I will edit my post according to your comment.

Comment: Definitely "nonrational" -- it's easy enough to come up with examples of $\beta = \frac pq \alpha$ for any rational $p/q$. You'll probably want to require at least that $\{1,\alpha,\beta\}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I guess, someone could just push [this result](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09392) up to $n=4$ or as the author conjectures, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Sounds (not!) easy.

Comment: @user3733558: If that results holds, $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2$, $\beta=\alpha^2$ will be a solution to the question as currently written. It looks somewhat iffy, though -- for example, the paper doesn't state _any_ concrete bound for any concrete number, even though it claims the bounds are effectively computable, and there is no kind of discussion of how large bounds to expect. The c.f. expansion of $\sqrt[3]2$ ([A002945](https://oeis.org/A002945)) has a 534 early on (and later a 7451), and OEIS doesn't mention any known bound.

Comment: @Troposphere I completely agree that it looks iffy. However, I'm probably missing something, but aren't your examples for $\alpha,\beta$ both algebraic of degree $3$? And if so, do we know that their sum will also be?

Comment: @user3733558: Yes, since we have $\alpha^3=2$, $\beta^3=4$, and $(\alpha+\beta)^3=6+6(\alpha+\beta)$. In general, whenever $x$ is algebraic of degree $n$, every integer-polynomial expression in $x$ will be algebraic of a degree that divides $n$ (or rational).

Comment: @Troposphere evidently, I'm not awake yet. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I tried $contfrac(a)=[3,1,1,3,1,3,3,1,..]$ following the pattern of the Thue-morse sequence, and $contfrac(b)=[2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,..]$ as above. Both cf's are bounded & aperiodic. But the continued fraction of $c=b+a$ seems to contain unbounded partial quotients...

Comment: Version now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389168/bounded-aperiodic-irrationals-with-bounded-aperiodic-sum